# how to play mp3 file in c# windows form visual studio 2013 windows8

Tags: c#, mp3

i want to play a ("Myfile.mp3)" file in my project and i added windows media player component to my project and used this codes but do not work!!? please help?

```
  axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL =("myfile.mp3");
  axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
```

Comment: *'but do not work'* Could you be a bit more specific? What *exactly* doesn't work? What is your error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code has to run perfectly as I´ve tested it:

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

wplayer.URL = "My MP3 file.mp3";
wplayer.controls.play();
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562461(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: can i check wplayer state with :                                                                                                                                                      wplayer.playState ==  WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying , it not working for me!

Comment: it code play file  just 5 second!!